# Function to display RGB arrays in R

Tags: r, jpeg, rstudio

I'm looking for a function to display RGB pictures represented as 3-dimensional arrays to RStudio graphics device. For example, I've read a jpeg

```
library(jpeg)    
pic <- readJPEG(example.jpg)
str(pic)
```

`num [1:360, 1:480, 1:3] 0.106 0.106 0.106 0.106 0.106 ...`

Then how to print it to RStudioGD? The thing is that I want to do some manipulations with this array, so I want to be able to look at the picture right in RStudio.

Comment: Try the example in `?readJPEG`

Comment: Oh, thank you. Should have looked more attentively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
h <- dim(pic)[1]
w <- dim(pic)[2]
plot(x = c(0, h), y = c(0, w), type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
rasterImage(pic, 0, 0, h, w)
```

Comment: You could run `par(mai = c(0,0,0,0))` first to make better use of the plot area. Also, there is no need to define `h` and `w`. You get the same result, if you just replace them by 1.